# Lighttpd Execute ./cgi-bin/index.cgi if exists in the folder

Tags: lighttpd

BusyBox httpd executes the `./cgi-bin/index.cgi` if it exists. This is similar to `index.php` but with the `/cgi-bin/` folder.
So for example I have the structure:

```
/api/
  cgi-bin/index.cgi
/blog/
  cgi-bin/index.cgi
  /rss/
    cgi-bin/index.cgi
```

So when request are going to `http://example.com/api/` they are actually handled by the `/www/api/cgi-bin/index.cgi` script.
When requested `http://example.com/blog/` it's processed by `/www/blog/cgi-bin/index.cgi` but the `/blog/rss/` path is processed by `/www/blog/rss/cgi-bin/index.cgi`.

But now I also want to support the Lighttpd webserver.
How can I achieve that?

This seems similar to [Making lighttpd redirect from www.example.com to www.example.com/cgi-bin/index.pl](https://serverfault.com/questions/404532/making-lighttpd-redirect-from-www-example-com-to-www-example-com-cgi-bin-index-p) but much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use lighttpd mod_indexfile:

`index-file.names = ( "cgi-bin/index.pl" )`

An alternative if you want to internally rewrite the target, try lighttpd mod_rewrite:

Generically:

`url.rewrite-once = ( ".*/(?:\?|$)" => "${url.path}cgi-bin/index.pl${qsa}" )`

More precisely for only the paths in your example:

```
url.rewrite-once =
  ( "^/(?:api|blog(?:/rss)?)/(?:\?|$)" => "${url.path}cgi-bin/index.pl${qsa}" )
```